# Google pie chart animation of the slices colors

Tags: javascript, animation, google-visualization

I have a Google pie chart that I try to animate using simple JavaScript code.

I wish to change to colors of my pie slices. Why my code is not working?

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);   

function drawChart() {
  var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
  ['A1', 0],
  ['Failed',1],
  ['A2', 0],
  ['Passed', 3],     
]);

 var colors1 = ['#ef7777', '#ef7777', '#b2d284', '#b2d284', '#f6c7b6'];
 var colors2 =  ['#ff00ff', '#ff00ff', '#02d2ff', '#02d2ff', '#f6c7b6'];
 var colors3 = colors2;

var options1 = {'title':'Logic', 'width':'50%', 'height':'50%', legend:{position:'none'}, 'is3D':true,  
chartArea: {width: '70%', height: '70%'},  
colors: colors3,    
    'backgroundColor': '#fef7f8',
    pieSliceTextStyle: {
            color: '#000000',
            bold: true,
            fontSize:16
        }
  }; 

var chart1 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart1')); 

  chart1.draw(data1, options1);
  var percent = 0;
        var handler = setInterval(function(){
            // values increment
            percent += 1;
            if (percent%2 == 1) {
            colors3 = colors1;
            }
            else
            {
            colors3 = colors2;
            }
            chart1.draw(data1, options1);

            if (percent > 74)

                clearInterval(handler);
        }, 333);  
}
```

So, I am setting here 2 arrays with color sets for my pie chart. The first have colors of red and green, the 2nd one have colors of blue and purple.

I wish to switch between these color sets continuously using the function "setInterval".

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why my code is not working? How to make an animation of the pie chart by change the pie colors...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**colors** is a key of your **options** object. The callback function of your setInterval call changes a variable called colors3 but you don't assign it to the original object so it won't ever be used.

```
    if (percent % 2 == 1) {
      colors3 = colors1;
    } else {
      colors3 = colors2;
    }
    options1.colors = colors3; // here we're assigning it!
    chart1.draw(data1, options1);
```